# Bokeh callback: Changing the geo source

Tags: python, callback, bokeh, geopandas

I'm trying to make an application using Bokeh that takes a small dataset and loads part of it based on a selected value for a `Select` menu- a dropdown menu. This filtered data is used later for generating some bar plots (quantities such as rate, score, and a normalized-score. I'll mention the rate only though). Yet, for two options in the dropdown menu, one can also map the data in a geographical map and I want to have both (normal mapping and geographical mapping) whenever is possible. The challenge, however, is that the geographical partitioning for those two is different: one corresponds to provinces of a country and the other to the counties.

Given that, I decided to

- always plot the usual bar plots,
- always plot the geographical plot as well: depending on the selected choice in the menu, either the provinces or the counties/cities must be plotted. When none of those two options are selected, I only plot the country border.

I have retrieved the shapefiles from my hard drive for `border`, `provinces` and `cities` and have managed to plot the bar graphs, the geographical plots, and the selection menu. The callback also is working fine as long as the bar plots are of concern (they change upon changing the choice in the menu). Yet it is not the case for the geographical plots. They stay as they are (as they should) as I didn't find the correct way to change `data_source` for them.

Here is a simplified version of my code.

```py
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
import json

from bokeh.io import show, output_notebook
from bokeh.layouts import column, row
from bokeh.models import GeoJSONDataSource, Panel, Tabs, LinearColorMapper, 
from bokeh.models.widgets import Select
from bokeh.palettes import Viridis256
from bokeh.plotting import figure, ColumnDataSource, curdoc

# this is needed for some preprocessing
from bokeh.models.glyphs import MultiPolygons


#1. loading shapefiles
shapefile_dir = 'a_directory/'

border = gpd.read_file(shapefile_dir + 'border.shp', encoding='utf8')
prov = gpd.read_file(shapefile_dir + 'provinces.shp',encoding='utf8')
city = gpd.read_file(shapefile_dir + 'counties.shp',encoding='utf8')

prov = prov.reindex(['ADM1_EN', 'ADM1_FA','Shape_Leng','Shape_Area','geometry'], axis=1)
city = city.reindex(['ADM2_EN', 'ADM2_FA','ADM1_EN', 'ADM1_FA','Shape_Leng','Shape_Area','geometry'], axis=1)

# some preprocessing 
# ...

#2.  loading the data
data = pd.read_excel('GeneralReport.xlsx')[0:-1]
data.rename(columns={'پاسخ کافی نیست':'insufficient',\
                     'از پاسخ رضایت دارم':'satisfied',\
                     'پاسخ بی ارتباط است':'irrelevant',\
                     'نام سازمان':'name'}, inplace=True)
data.name = data.name.map(lambda x: x.strip())
data.set_index('name', inplace=True)


# some simple data manipulations 
# ...


# 3. defining some functions that will be used later
def selector(select):
"""this function reads the menu value and reforms it if it is needed. the returned value is a string or a list of strings."""
# ...


def filtering(df, name_str):
    """filters the dataset based on the `name_str` and sorts it by the `rate` property`"""

    cond = pd.Series(index = df.index, data=False)
    if type(name_str)==type([]):
        for s in name_str:
            cond += data.index.str.startswith(s)
    else:
        cond += data.index.str.startswith(name_str)
    filtered = df[cond]
    return filtered.sort_values('rate').reset_index()


def filter_for_map(df, name_str):
    """checks the `name_sting` and returns the proper geopandas dataframe"""

   _df = df.copy()
    _df.index = _df.name.map(lambda x: x.replace(name_str,'').strip())

    if (name_str=='شهرداری' or name_str=='استانداری'): 
        if name_str=='شهرداری': # counties shall be returned
            R = pd.Series(index=city.city_fa)
            geo = gpd.GeoDataFrame(geometry = city.geometry)
        else:  # provinces shall be returned
            R = pd.Series(index=prov.prov_fa)
            geo = gpd.GeoDataFrame(geometry = prov.geometry)

        S = R.copy()
        SN = R.copy()
        R[R.index.isin(_df.index)]=_df.rate
        S[S.index.isin(_df.index)]=_df.score
        SN[SN.index.isin(_df.index)]=_df['score-normalized']

        geo['name'] = R.index
        geo['score'] = S.values
        geo['rate'] = R.values
        geo['score_normalized'] = SN.values

    else:  # borders shall be returned
        geo = gpd.GeoDataFrame(geometry = border.geometry)
        geo['name'] = pd.np.random.randint(len(geo))
        geo['score'] = None
        geo['rate'] = None
        geo['score_normalized'] = None

    return GeoJSONDataSource(geojson=geo.to_json())


#4. plotting
name_str = 'استانداری'

TOOLS = "pan,wheel_zoom,box_zoom,reset,hover,save"
FIG_SETTING = {'plot_width':900, 'plot_height':400, 'tools':"hover,wheel_zoom,pan,reset"}
BAR_SETTING = {'x':'name', 'width':0.9, 'line_color':'white' }
MAP_SETTING = {'fill_alpha':1, 'line_color':'black', 'line_width':0.25}

# bar plots
df = filtering(data, name_str)
source = ColumnDataSource.from_df(df)

p1 = figure(x_range=source['name'],**FIG_SETTING)
r1= p1.vbar(top='rate',fill_color={'field': 'rate','transform': color_mapper}, source=source, **BAR_SETTING )
t1 = Panel(child=p1, title='Rate')
p1.xaxis[0].major_label_orientation=pd.np.pi/2


# map plots
geo_source= filter_for_map(df, name_str)

p4 = figure(title="Rate", tooltips=[("نام", "@name"), ("ًنرخ پاسخ‌گویی", "@rate")], tools=TOOLS,)
r4 = p4.patches('xs', 'ys', fill_color={'field': 'rate','transform': color_mapper}, source=geo_source, **MAP_SETTING,)
t4 = Panel(child=p4, title='Rate')


def callback(attr, old, new):
    name_str = selector(select)
    df = filtering(data, name_str)
    src = ColumnDataSource.from_df(df)
    geo_src = filter_for_map(df, name_str)

    r1.data_source.data= src
    p1.x_range.factors= list(src['name'])

    # I'm not sure about the following line
    r4.update(data_source= geo_src)

select = Select(title="دسته‌بندی", value="شهرداری",\
                options=["استانداری", "وزارت", "دانشگاه", "بانک",  "سازمان", "شرکت", "مرکز",  "شهرداری", "صندوق", "موسسه",  "معاونت", "بنیاد", "بیمه", "اداره","غیره"])
select.on_change('value', callback)

tabs1 = Tabs(tabs=[ t1 ])
tabs2 = Tabs(tabs=[ t4 ])
layout = row(tabs1,tabs2)
curdoc().add_root(column(select,layout))
```

I'd like to draw your attention to the callback function where I'm not sure how to update/redefine the `geo_src` such that Bokeh updates it whenever the callback is triggered. So far only the barplot `t1` behaves correctly and the other map `t4` remains static (losses the source and therefore hovering won't work either after the menu's choice is changed).

I appreciate any help.

Comment: If this is supported (not sure) then the way to do it is to update the `.geojson` property of the existing data source, not create a new `GeoJSONDataSource`.

Answer (score 2):

I hope this can be useful to someone in the future. I solved this problem by updating the geojson of the geosource. In the case above, you would update callback as such:

```
def filter_for_map(df, name_str):
    ... #removed code
    return geo #just return your modified data frame

def callback(attr, old, new):
    ...
    geo_src = filter_for_map(df, name_str)
    ....
    geo_source.geojson = geo_src.to_json() #set the existing source's geojson attribute to your dataframe converted in json file
```

Do not create a new GeoJSONDataSource, you must update the existing source using the parameters available (like the to_json).

As I do not have your code, I cannot check this solution, but this approach does update the geosource on my local. Best wishes.